# Array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of nested objects.

```
const arr = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "java",
  answers: {
    q1: "ex",
    q2: "ex",
    q3: "ex",
  },
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "css",
  answers: {
    q1: "ex",
    q2: "ex",
    q3: "ex",
  },
},];
```

For example : I want to access and diplay "q1" from the first "answer" object . How can I do that?

Comment: `arr[0].answers.q1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference array items using their numerical index, you want `arr[0].answers.q1`

```js
const arr = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "java",
  answers: {
    q1: "ex",
    q2: "ex",
    q3: "ex",
  },
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "css",
  answers: {
    q1: "ex",
    q2: "ex",
    q3: "ex",
  },
},];

const example = document.getElementById('example');
example.innerHTML = arr[0].answers.q1;
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: this question has been asked before